# Can I create an alias of a type in Golang?

Tags: go, types, alias

I'm struggling with my learning of Go.

I found this neat implementation of a Set in go: [gopkg.in/fatih/set.v0](https://github.com/fatih/set), but I'd prefer naming my sets with a more explicit name that `set.Set`, doing something like:

```
type View set.Set
```

In essence, I want my `View` type to inherit `set.Set`'s methods. Because, well, `View` **is a** `set.Set` of descriptors. But I know Go is pretty peaky on inheritance, and typing in general.

For now I've been trying the following *kinda* inheritance, but it's causing loads of errors when trying to use some functions like `func Union(set1, set2 Interface, sets ...Interface) Interface` or `func (s *Set) Merge(t Interface)`:

```
type View struct {
    set.Set
}
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to achieve what I want in a Go-like way, or if I'm just trying to apply my good-ol' OO practices to a language that discards them, please.

Comment: Don't try to write Go like OO languages with inheritance. There is _no_ inheritance, so you're only going to create more confusion. If you want to automatically delegate methods and fields, you can use embedding like in your second example, which is just fine, but keep in mind that's only a form of composition.

Comment: So, your advice is using the original set.Set type as is? Since using set's functions is so cumbersome with the embedded type? It's not so bad, I just dived straight into inheritance before thinking of what I was doing.

Comment: If you're interested, there's a good article here on the topic by William Kennedy: https://www.goinggo.net/2016/10/reducing-type-hierarchies.html

Comment: @AdrienLuxey: yes, just use the set type directly if that's what you want. You would have to show an example of the problems you had with embedding, since it's not changing any behavior of `set.Set` at all.

Comment: @thoeni Thanks for the tutorial, I'm on it :)
And thanks JimB for the precisions, I'll do as told! Go is quite braintwisting, for the neophyte... I'll make it!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If anyone else is coming back to this question, as of [Go 1.9](https://blog.golang.org/go1.9) type aliases are now supported.

A type alias has the form: `type T1 = T2`

So in your example you can just do `type View = set.Set` and everything will work as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Note, I think the simple aliasing you proposed initially is syntactically valid though having had a quick look at the set library, rather than aliasing `set.Set` it might make more sense to alias `set.Interface`, e.g.:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"

  set "gopkg.in/fatih/set.v0"
)

// View is a type alias for the set.Interface interface
type View set.Interface

// Display takes one of our View types in order to print it.
func Display(view View) {
  fmt.Println(view.List())
}

func main() {
  // create our first set.Interface or View
  v1 := set.New()
  v1.Add("foo")

  // create our second set.Interface or View
  v2 := set.New("bar")

  // call a set function
  v3 := set.Union(v1, v2)

  // call our function that takes a View
  Display(v3)
}
```

You may have noticed I'm cheating somehow because I make no real mention of the aliased type in the above code other than in defining the parameter to the `Display` function above which you'll note takes in a `View` instance rather than a `set.Interface`. If you have lots of functions working on these things, then that might read more expressively for your domain.

Note that because our `View` type is an alias to an interface type, it precludes adding your own functions to that type as Go doesn't allow us to have an interface receiver type for a function (I might be expressing that incorrectly). By this I mean that you can't do anything like:

```
func (v View) Display() string {
  return v.String()
}
```

In summary I think aliasing things is fine, it can make internal APIs more readable, and you can lean on the compiler to help eliminate certain classes of errors; however this doesn't allow you to add functionality to the custom type. If this is required an alternate approach would be necessary, either embedding or simple composition (i.e. a `View` has a `Set`).